# wp_validate_logged_in_cookie

Tags: functions, cookies

I would like to understand this function, its purpose and its working.

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_validate_logged_in_cookie/

writes that

> Checks the logged-in cookie if the previous auth cookie could not be validated and parsed.

Isn't this

> could *be* validated

? Inspecting the source code:

```
function wp_validate_logged_in_cookie( $user_id ) {
    if ( $user_id ) {
        return $user_id;
    }

    if ( is_blog_admin() || is_network_admin() || empty($_COOKIE[LOGGED_IN_COOKIE] ) ) {
        return false;
    }

    return wp_validate_auth_cookie( $_COOKIE[LOGGED_IN_COOKIE], 'logged_in' );
}
```

it looks as if it mostly returns the user id when it exists and this has nothing to do with any cookies.

How should I interpret this function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`wp_validate_logged_in_cookie()`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.8/src/wp-includes/user.php#L315) comment from source:

```
/**
 * Validates the logged-in cookie.
 *
 * Checks the logged-in cookie if the previous auth cookie could not be
 * validated and parsed.
 *
 * This is a callback for the {@see 'determine_current_user'} filter, rather than API.
 *
 * @since 3.9.0
 *
 * @param int|bool $user_id The user ID (or false) as received from the
 *                       determine_current_user filter.
 * @return int|false User ID if validated, false otherwise. If a user ID from
 *                   an earlier filter callback is received, that value is returned.
 */
```

It is a default callback function for the filter hook [`determine_current_user`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/determine_current_user/) used by the private function [`_wp_get_current_user()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/_wp_get_current_user/) and some plugins.

Its default usage as defined in *wp-includes/default-filters.php line 371*:

`add_filter( 'determine_current_user', 'wp_validate_logged_in_cookie', 20 );`

`_wp_get_current_user()`'s use of the filter from [line 2523 of *wp-includes/user.php*](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.8/src/wp-includes/user.php#L2524):

```
     /**
     * Filters the current user.
     *
     * The default filters use this to determine the current user from the
     * request's cookies, if available.
     *
     * Returning a value of false will effectively short-circuit setting
     * the current user.
     *
     * @since 3.9.0
     *
     * @param int|bool $user_id User ID if one has been determined, false otherwise.
     */
    $user_id = apply_filters( 'determine_current_user', false );
```

In this usage `wp_validate_logged_in_cookie()` is passed the argument `false`, and would thus be forced to run [`wp_validate_auth_cookie()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_validate_auth_cookie/) if there is a cookie and we are on the frontend.

[`wp_validate_auth_cookie()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_validate_auth_cookie/) returns a user id if the cookie is valid.

---

The full source of `_wp_get_current_user()`, to see the above quoted `apply_filters()` line in context. Note that if no user id is returned to it, user id is set to an invalid `0` and immediately returned; denoting no logged in user.

```
function _wp_get_current_user() {
    global $current_user;

    if ( ! empty( $current_user ) ) {
        if ( $current_user instanceof WP_User ) {
            return $current_user;
        }

        // Upgrade stdClass to WP_User
        if ( is_object( $current_user ) && isset( $current_user->ID ) ) {
            $cur_id = $current_user->ID;
            $current_user = null;
            wp_set_current_user( $cur_id );
            return $current_user;
        }

        // $current_user has a junk value. Force to WP_User with ID 0.
        $current_user = null;
        wp_set_current_user( 0 );
        return $current_user;
    }

    if ( defined('XMLRPC_REQUEST') && XMLRPC_REQUEST ) {
        wp_set_current_user( 0 );
        return $current_user;
    }

    /**
     * Filters the current user.
     *
     * The default filters use this to determine the current user from the
     * request's cookies, if available.
     *
     * Returning a value of false will effectively short-circuit setting
     * the current user.
     *
     * @since 3.9.0
     *
     * @param int|bool $user_id User ID if one has been determined, false otherwise.
     */
    $user_id = apply_filters( 'determine_current_user', false );
    if ( ! $user_id ) {
        wp_set_current_user( 0 );
        return $current_user;
    }

    wp_set_current_user( $user_id );

    return $current_user;
}
```